# Rails: Spaces in string used for name causes validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, model

I have a User Group table with a group_name value that is entered when the group is created. If there is a space in the group name, for example "Team Lol", the group name is still created, but it is not assigned to the current user, and it throws the error message in my if/else statement in the controller. Code is as follows:

Controller:

```
def create
    @group = current_user.create_user_group(group_params)
    current_user.user_group = @group
    current_user.save
    if @group.valid?
        redirect_to '/user_groups/'+@group.group_name, :notice => "Your group has been created"
    else
        redirect_to '/user_groups/', :error => "Error: group name may already be taken. Search, or try a new name."
    end
end
```

Model

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :users

has_secure_password
validates :password, :presence => true

validates :group_name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

before_validation :strip_blanks

def strip_blanks
  self.group_name = self.group_name.strip
end
```

Create form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Group Name">Enter group name</label>
    <%= f.input :group_name, :required => true, :autofocus => true, :maxlength => 40, :input_html => { :class => "form-control" }, :label => false, :placeholder => "Group name" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Password">Password</label>
    <%= f.input :password, :required => true, :autofocus => true, :maxlength => 40, :input_html => { :class => "form-control" }, :label => false, :placeholder => "Group password" %>
</div>
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-md btn-warning" %>
</div>
```

Comment: please post your error message.

Comment: No error message from rails, the page loads and runs through this portion of my if/else statement:  else
        redirect_to '/user_groups/', :error => "Error: group name may already be taken. Search, or try a new name."
    end

Comment: Can you post the way you have set up the group association on the User model as well? I believe that your code tries to save the group twice (once via the create_user_group call and once upon user save).

Comment: class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :user_group
  has_many :items, through: :user_groups
end

Comment: Viewing my log output, I think you're correct Lazarus. I see that the app creates the group, saves it to the user, then tries to create the group again, sees that it's already created, and throws the error. What might be the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it - it was a URI issue.
When a name with a space was created, the user was routed to /user_groups/The A Team.

It my routes I have /user_groups/:group_name routing to that group's home page.
However, since those spaces don't register correctly, the app seems to run another POST request to create a group instead.

I simply changed my redirect to redirect_to '/user_groups/'+@group.group_name.gsub(/\s/,'%20'), :notice => "Your group has been created" 
Let me know if you think there's any problems with the way I handled this.

Thanks for everyones help,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are already creating the group in this line:

`@group = current_user.create_user_group(group_params)`

then, you're assigning (and Rails tries to create it again) here:

`current_user.user_group = @group
current_user.save`

I think you should remove the last two calls, given that if

`@group = current_user.create_user_group(group_params)`

succeeded, then the group is valid. The action that will follow is to redirect there.

*Disclaimer: this is off the top of my head*.